# How can i change the length of the title that it is dynamic?

Tags: html, css, highcharts

[image]At the moment I have a static `backgroundcolor` for the title. So if your resolution is smaller than the original, the `backgroundcolor` widens. My goal is to make the `backgroundcolor` dynamic, for the resolution. If somebody has a bigger or smaller resolution, the `backgroundcolor` of the title should be maximum but not widen
[image]

Comment: Have you already try to use the `responsive` options? https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive.rules

Comment: Is this really dynamic. I thought it is static too, because you give it a specific value. I need something, which dynamically change if the resolution of a monitor is smaller or bigger. It always should be the maximum length too.

Comment: I don't really understand your requirement. The title is fully responsive and adjusts to the container dimensions which is included. "So if your resolution is smaller than the original, the backgroundcolor widens." - What does it mean? Are you able to reproduce this behaviour on some online editor and explain the steps to reproduce the `backgroundcolor` widens?

Comment: I work on a Full HD Monitor and it´s all fine. But if i look at my Chart on a smaller Notebook with HD for example, the bgcolor of the title widens up to the chart.

Comment: May I see the demo of this issue?

Comment: Here 2 pics, the second is on the full hd and the first on my notebook

Comment: It shouldn't work this way. Could you reproduce this issue on some online editor which I could debug?

Comment: There is the code for the title: https://jsfiddle.net/BS1010/stzpy83v/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the code. As the title is rendered as outstanding HTML element his width could be dynamically changed in the **render** callback.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p96a2fn0/

```
chart: {
    events: {
    render() {
      let chart = this;

      chart.title.element.style.width = chart.chartWidth + 'px'
    }
  }
},
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Please test this settings in your app.

Comment: Now it works perfect, thank you. btw i don´t know why grafana show me errors although it works ;D

Comment: Do you have an idea, how it works directed to the left?

Comment: @BS1010 `Do you have an idea, how it works directed to the left?` Could you explain more precisely what do you have in mind?

Comment: I´ve solved the problem by the way, but i can explain quick for you. I work in Grafana and there are transparent frames. Directed to the right, i set the length to the end, but directed to the left, were like 20px before the title starts. And i thought about complex methods, but just have to set x=-20 ;D

Comment: @BS1010 so as I understand your issue is solved and you don't need any more help? :)